# Design patterns /Better way to write Javascript UI validations

Tags: javascript, validation, design-patterns

I have a json object with some fields: name, promocode, salutation etc.

```
{
  name: "xx",
  promocode: "asd123",
  salutation: "Mr"
};
```

For each field I need to check blank as well as conditions to that field.For now I have kept all the field names in an array and I am looping through that array and checking for null/non empty value dynamically. For a specific condition I might have to write some code like:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; arr++) {
  if (object[arr[i]] == "promocode") {
    validatepromocode(obj.promocode);
  }

  if (object[arr[i]] == "salutation") {
   validatesalutation(obj.promocode)
  }
}
```

which I feel is not the best way to write such code. Can there be some design pattern/alternative approach to make such code better.

Comment: I'm really confused by your example. Assuming `obj` an `object` should be the same thing, i.e. the payload to be validated, it seems you're checking if the payload contains a field `promocode` which has the value `"promocode"`? What is the purpose of the array that holds the field names?

Comment: Take a look at libraries such as `ValidateJS`: https://validatejs.org/ They make these kinds of "model checking" easier. You define a `JSON` in which you configure how objects should be validated, then run any object with your validation object through a `validate` function included in the library. It will return a response of an array containing all the errors.

Comment: @vijoc : the object can have many fields the array just holds the name of mandatory fields.

Comment: Why are the names in a separate array?

Comment: just to idetify the mandatory fields , assume the json object is having 15 fields and 7 of them are mandatory and I want to perform not empty/blank check for them.

Comment: [schema-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/schema-validator) has a JSON-based specification for validation that constructs a function which you can pass your object to directly, and have it check everything for you.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, could you post a jsbin or a code snippet?

Comment: what I need to do is to provide an alert message for the field that fails validation. So , as soon as any one of the mandatory fields fails validation , I am showing the alert message and breaking the loop.

Comment: As already mentioned model validation is the way to go and here is another library: [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron)